# View.RenderAsync() causes Cannot access a closed Stream exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views, razorengine

I'm developing net6.0 MVC app. I use partial view rendering to the string format in my app. I make Ajax request to the app and expect it to form a Json containing rendered partial view as a prop.
There is a method I use to render partial to a string below

```
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(Controller controller, string partialPath, object model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(partialPath))
            {
                //Set Action name as partial name
                partialPath = controller.GetActionNameFromRouteData();
            }

            controller.ViewData.Model = model;

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                // Find partial view file
                var viewEngine = DependencyResolverHelper.GetService<ICompositeViewEngine>();
                var viewResult = viewEngine.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, partialPath, false);
                
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw, new HtmlHelperOptions());
                
                viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

The problem is once I call `viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` it seems it captures and blocks Response.Body of current HttpContext so I can't form and return expected json anymore.
There is custom json result class I use to form the response

[image]

The exception

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.IO.Pipelines.StreamPipeWriter.FlushAsyncInternal(Boolean writeToStream, ReadOnlyMemory`1 data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Web.Controllers.BaseCustomController`1.JsonNetResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
```

Could anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by creating fake http context:

```cs
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(Controller controller, string partialPath, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(partialPath))
    {
        //Set Action name as partial name
        partialPath = controller.GetActionNameFromRouteData();
    }

    var httpContextFactory = DependencyResolverHelper.GetService<IHttpContextFactory>();
    var newHttpContext = httpContextFactory.Create(new FeatureCollection(controller.HttpContext.Features));

    using var newHttpContextBody = new MemoryStream();
    newHttpContext.Response.Body = newHttpContextBody;
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(newHttpContext, controller.ControllerContext.RouteData, new ActionDescriptor());

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        // Find partial view file
        var viewEngine = DependencyResolverHelper.GetService<ICompositeViewEngine>();
        var viewResult = viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, partialPath, false);
        var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(controller.MetadataProvider, controller.ModelState) { Model = model };

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(actionContext, viewResult.View, viewData, controller.TempData, sw, new HtmlHelperOptions());
        viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

`new FeatureCollection(...)` is important. If you look at source of [`DefaultHttpResponse`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d40eea990edd1ac7205a983cbe4d13a71fd4ad68/src/Http/Http/src/Internal/DefaultHttpResponse.cs#L78), when changing response's body, `IHttpResponseBodyFeature` feature is replaced in http context. That's why `new FeatureCollection(...)` is used here, because it creates a snapshot of original http context's features, so original `IHttpResponseBodyFeature` feature won't be replaced, e.g. original response body won't be changed.